# Firestore cloud function to delete documents

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently trying to delete documents that got created in a certain path of my firestore project 10 mins after creation. I'd like to do this with Typescript and I currently got this code working:

```
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userId}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    console.log('user created');
});
```

How can I add a sleep of 10 mins and delete the created document afterwards? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not possible with Cloud Functions and Firestore alone.  You'll need to bring some external scheduler to invoke a function after some delay.  The Google Cloud engineers are aware that many people need to do something like this, and it's being looked into.

Comment: I thought about calling the function, add a sleep of 1 hour and then delete the document. That should be possible right?

Comment: That's not possible.  All functions have a maximum configurable timeout of 9 minutes.  After the timeout, the function will be forcibly stopped.

Comment: Hm... Ok, which external scheduler would be a good one to use?